# Use HTML5 Canvas to capture frames from a video

Tags: html, video, canvas, frame, capture

I was trying to capture a frame from a video and drawing it to a canvas using HTML5, but the below code is not working correctly. When I use `.mp4` format video source and click on the start button, the canvas is filled in with black.

But I can get correct capture images for '.ogv' format video source. This is a code used for capture a frame:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var videoId = 'video';
    var scaleFactor = 0.25;
    var snapshots = [];

    /**
    * Captures a image frame from the provided video element.
    *
    * @param {Video} video HTML5 video element from where the image frame will be captured.
    * @param {Number} scaleFactor Factor to scale the canvas element that will be return. This is an optional parameter.
    *
    * @return {Canvas}
    */
    function capture(video, scaleFactor) {
        if(scaleFactor == null){
            scaleFactor = 1;
        }
        var w = video.videoWidth * scaleFactor;
        var h = video.videoHeight * scaleFactor;
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width  = w;
        canvas.height = h;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);
        return canvas;
    } 

    /**
    * Invokes the <code>capture</code> function and attaches the canvas element to the DOM.
     */
    function shoot(){
        var video  = document.getElementById(videoId);
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        var canvas = capture(video, scaleFactor);
        canvas.onclick = function(){
            window.open(this.toDataURL());
        };
        snapshots.unshift(canvas);
        output.innerHTML = '';
        for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
            output.appendChild(snapshots[i]);
        }
    }
</script>
```